# PHP: How to I convert a 3D array into an mysql result object?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

The answer might be write two functions! However, maybe a little knowledge that I do not have will help avoid a heck of a lot of re-factoring or database usage.

I have a function with the very common syntax of:

```
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
// do some stuff
}
```

Most of the time, the $row will be a mysql object with zero, one or more rows therein. Simple.

However, it would be very handy if I could also utilise a three dimensional PHP array (previously built to be a bunch of "rows" with three key & value pairs) without handling them differently.

The question I have is "What do I need to do to a 3D array to "convert" it to a mysql object that will work without change in the above example"?

Comment: I did not understand why you want to convert arrays to mysql objects. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it enough. The function that works with the mysql object (several rows) expects to be passed a mysql result object. In some cases I'd like to reuse this function where I have an 3D array (basically the same idea of several variables repeating like rows) and I'd like to know if there is a quick way to convert that array into the same format as the mysql result object. If not then I probably need to change the function to work with an array and convert mysql results to arrays before hitting the function - just trying to avoid that.

Comment: OR you can store the results in two different variables, one in `mysql result object` format and another one casted/converted as `array`. Can you do it? If you can't I'd suggest you to post some snippets of your code that might be helpful for us to have more info and solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, that is another way of approaching it. I've basically built to to test if it gets and array or a mysql object and if the latter then turn it into an array so the next bit of code works on array whatever option is before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to convert into a mysql object without writing to a tmp table and reading it back in. The following will deal with either sql statement or array turning up which then negates the need to convert as the question asked.

```
$all_rows = $notify->notification_sql(); // This either returns an SQL statement ready to run OR a set of rows in an array

if (!is_array($all_rows)) { // If it's not an array, run the SQL query and put it into an array of rows
    $result = $db->sql_query($all_rows);
    $all_rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $all_rows[] = $row;
    }
}

foreach...
```